# stylesheet_link_tag not finding css file in sinatra app

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am deploying a simple Sinatra app on my own machine, and I am trying to use this line to reference my stylesheet:

```
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag './stylesheet.css' %>
```

My stylesheet.css is located in the root directory of my app, but it is not applied to the any pages of my app. I am using shotgun to run the server. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: this returns the error `uninitialized constant Sinatra::Application::Rails` keep in mind I'm using Sinatra not Rails

Comment: sorry did not notice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to put my stylesheet.css file in a `/public` directory in the root of my application and that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is most likely the `.` which is confusing the browser. I am also using Sinatra in one of my apps, but as I use [Erector](http://erector.rubyforge.org) as the view-engine I have to guess a little about the root causes in an erb-template. Nevertheless I can tell you that I use "absolute" paths when referring to my assets which "implicitly" will be relative to my apps root path on the server.

Keep in mind that the browser will in the end generate an "absolute" URL from the address of your site and the link you provide. I am not sure how much confusion your `.` will introduce into the webserver at hand, try leaving it out. It might also try to refer to your "current" URL, but in that case it should at least work on your home page.

Also it would be easier to help you if you would not just post your erb-template, but also the resulting HTML-code. Most likely it will tell you about the problem anyway. Try pasting the resulting URL into your browsers address-bar an see wether you can get your css directly.